# MockServerClient field is always null with Springboot and Junit5

Tags: junit, spring-boot-test, mockserver

I'm following the "Running MockServer via Spring TestExecutionListener @MockServerTest" from this official [guide](https://www.mock-server.com/mock_server/running_mock_server.html#spring_test_exec_listener).

In my Junit5 test I want to instantiate a `MockServerClient` field.
To isolate I created a new project with just this test class:

```
import org.example.MockConfig;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockserver.client.MockServerClient;
import org.mockserver.springtest.MockServerTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;

@MockServerTest
//@RunWith(SpringRunner.class) Not needed in JUnit5
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MockConfig.class)
public class MockTest {

    private MockServerClient client;

    @Test
    void name() {
        assert client != null; //it fails.
    }
}
```

`gradle.build` file:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group = 'org.example'
version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:3.2.1'
    testImplementation platform('org.junit:junit-bom:5.9.1')
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter'
    testImplementation 'org.mock-server:mockserver-spring-test-listener-no-dependencies:5.15.0'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

According to the documentation, it should work.
I auto wired the field but still fails.

Any clue or workaround that I can use?

*Update*

The following depency was added to gradle.build file for completeness:

```
testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:3.2.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

When using JUnit 5 (JUnit Jupiter to be precise), you need to add `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)` to your test class in that case otherwise the `MockServerTestExecutionListener` will not be taken into account behind the scenes. With JUnit 4, `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` did the trick.

Try this:

```java
@MockServerTest
//@RunWith(SpringRunner.class) -> JUnit 4
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class) // -> JUnit Jupiter (aka. JUnit 5)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MockConfig.class)
public class MockTest {

    private MockServerClient client;

    @Test
    void name() {
        assert client != null; //it fails.
    }
}
```

For more theoretical input on the `SpringExtension`, you can refer to this [article](https://rieckpil.de/what-the-heck-is-the-springextension-used-for/).

Comment: Can't test that solution because it gives the error:  

    `> Standard Commons Logging discovery in action with spring-jcl: please remove  commons-logging.jar from classpath in order to avoid potential conflicts.`

I removed the dependency from spring 
`> testImplementation ('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:3.2.1'){     exclude group:"ch.qos.logback"} `
, but still got the same error. There should be a work around for this issue but can't figure it out.

Comment: I reported an [issue](https://github.com/mock-server/mockserver/issues/1828)

Comment: I'm not quite sure if that's related to this issue, but let's see